# ENUM confusion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, html

This is my field in the table
`enabled enum('True','False');`

In the form which one is correct:

```
<select name="status">
<option value="True">True</option>
<option value="False">False</option>
</select>
```

OR

```
<select name="status">
<option value="1">True</option>
<option value="0">False</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Either way is correct; it's up to your application logic to decide the values when you insert into your DB. Also, is a select the best choice for a Boolean input? I don't think so.

Comment: ya, you are correct. radio button would be much better..thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both are correct semantically, it will be easier for you to use the first solution, because then you don't need any mapping of values.

Especially, because you have chosen `'True'` to be the first value and `'False'` to be the second one in your `enum` column, you might have major confusion with booleans vs ordinals (`1` and `0` as booleans, vs. `1` and `2` as ordinals).

Check out the documentation about enums and the automatic mapping of indexes to enum literals: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html